# PCA affects similarity comparisons even when keeping all the dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Consider:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def do_pca(X, n_components):
    print(f"Doing PCA from {X.shape[0]} vectors")
    pca = PCA(n_components=n_components)
    X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)
    print('Explained variance:',
          sum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_[:n_components]))
    return pca

def by_relevance(vectors, key_vector):
    rankings = [
        (i, cosine_similarity(v.reshape(1,-1), key_vector.reshape(1,-1)))
        for i, v in enumerate(vectors)]
    rankings.sort(key=lambda el:-el[1])
    for i, r in rankings:
        print(i, r)

np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.random((50, 20))
pca = do_pca(X, n_components=20)

X = X[:5]
key_vector = X[[0]]
by_relevance(X, key_vector)
print()
by_relevance(pca.transform(X), pca.transform(key_vector))
```

This code performs PCA on 50 vectors, while keeping as many components as there are dimensions. The function `by_relevance` sorts vectors by similarity to the given vector. We call this function twice - once before and once after the transformation. Since all the components are kept, I would expect similar results for both invocations. However, this is the output:

```
Doing PCA from 50 vectors
Explained variance: 1.0
0 [[1.]]
4 [[0.78738484]]
1 [[0.73532448]]
3 [[0.71538191]]
2 [[0.6614021]]

0 [[1.]]
4 [[0.01659682]]
3 [[-0.02417426]]
1 [[-0.02855172]]
2 [[-0.03232985]]
```

Why is the ranking affected and how come the last four similarities became so small?

Comment: Sklearn PCA centers the data. More info: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189822/how-does-centering-make-a-difference-in-pca-for-svd-and-eigen-decomposition

Comment: @Anonymous Sure, but I don't see the connection. How does this answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine similarity between random samples should be close to zero. The reason why your cosine similarity is so high for your un-transformed data, is that all points/vectors are lying the first quadrant. If you de-mean your data before computing the PCs, the results are much more similar between the two conditions, namely a cosine similarity of 1 for the matching vector and a cosine similarity of zero everywhere else.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.random((50, 20))
X -= np.full_like(X, 0.5)
pca = PCA(n_components=20).fit(X)

X = X[:5]
key_vector = X[[0]]

print(cosine_similarity(X, key_vector))
print(cosine_similarity(pca.transform(X), pca.transform(key_vector)))

# [[ 1.        ]
#  [-0.01928803]
#  [ 0.0100122 ]
#  [-0.06792705]
#  [ 0.01940078]]
# [[ 1.        ]
#  [-0.02855172]
#  [-0.03232985]
#  [-0.02417426]
#  [ 0.01659682]]
```